# Create a C++/CLI Project in visual studio 2015 with Platform toolset v120 (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

I am using Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) in Windows 10. I have one c++ project which is written with platform toolset v120. Now I want to use the codes of this project in my C# application. So I decide to create a C++/CLI Project (Class Library) and write a wrapper for the mentioned codes to be able to use them in my C# application. The problem is that when I change the platform toolset of my C++/CLI project to v120, the compiler give me this error:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'MSVCMRTD.lib'
```

But it works with the default platform toolset (v140). Please be informed that I don't have written any code in my C++/CLI project. I think one of the solutions is to install the whole Visual Studio 2013 besides 2015 version which is not a good solution. (I am not going to even try it). Any solution except installing Visual Studio 2013 would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and bring it here for further uses. I searched the library in my computer and add it to the "Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories" in my project's properties.